# Accesing to a print remotely from WEB API

Tags: python, django, network-printers

I used Django to develop a WEB API which allows me to register food orders and I want them to be sent directly to my EPSON TM-m30 command printer. 
This command printer would be connected via ETHERNET to my modem.

For printing I use python-escpos module, which works fine when I run my app locally as following:

```
p = printer.Network("192.168...")
p.text('Hello world')
p.cut
```

I'm hosting my app in Digital ocean with Ubuntu 18.04 VM.
As expected, my printer is not discoverable when I run my code from the digital ocean server... so what I supposed to do in order to allow that?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know what port is used by printer but if you know it then you may try in router redirect this port to your printer's local IP - `192.168...`. Then your code may use your router's external IP to connect to your router and it will redirect it to your printer.

Comment: or you can create local web server which will have access to local printer and then in router redirect port 80 to your local server. Now code on external server will have to send data to local server using `"router_external_IP:80"` and local server will use `printer.Network("192.168...")`

Comment: @furas I tried with port forwarding with my router. I assigned my printer IP to port 80 but nothing happened when I call the print with "ippublc:80".

Comment: printer may use different port as default. Port 80 can be useful if you use local WWW server (defaul port 80) which will translate HTTP request to `printer.Network("192.168...")`

Comment: @furas it's okey right now. It worked with port 9100, and calling then ippublic! 9100 port seems to be used by printers generally. Thanks anyway!